# AWS CloudHSM AES-256 bit keys generation using PKCS#11 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, pkcs#11, hsm

I am using the PKCS#11 API to generate AES-256 bit keys in AWS CloudHSM.

I believe I can generate the key successfully using (C_GenerateKey) however, when I try to print the value of the key, I get a "CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID" error on the first call to C_GetAttributeValue.

I do set the CKA_EXTRACTABLE option on the key while generating it. 
Here is a snippet of the code -

```
 set_attr(keyTemplate[n_attr], CKA_EXTRACTABLE, &_true, sizeof(_true));

 set_ATTR(keyTemplate[n_attr], CKA_VALUE_LEN, &key_length, sizeof(key_length));

 rv = pfunc11->C_GenerateKey(session, &mechanism, keyTemplate, n_attr, &hSecretKey);
 if (rv != CKR_OK)
 {
    printf("ERROR: rv=0x%08X: C_GenerateKey failed\n", (unsigned int)rv);
    return false;
 }
 else
 {
    rv = pfunc11->C_GetAttributeValue(session, hSecretKey, dataTemplate, 1);
    if(rv != CKR_OK)
    {
     printf("ERROR: rv=0x%08X: C_GetAttributeValue failed\n", (unsigned int)rv);
     return false;
    }
```

If I set the "CKA_SENSITIVE" option to false, I get an error (CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT) during generation of the key saying the template is invalid.

How can I print the value of the AES key in my application ?

Comment: Non-sensitive keys can be denied with policy configuration (e.g. `No Clear PINs` for SafeNet). I don't know AWS CloudHsm so can't help here...Good luck!

Comment: Apparently CloudHSM does not honor the CKA_SENSITIVE attribute at the moment. They are working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Handling of the CKA_SENSITIVE attribute has been [fixed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/KnownIssues.html#ki-pkcs11-sdk) in v 1.1.1 of the CloudHSM v2 client libraries.

You should really contemplate why you want to get the plain text value of your AES key. The reason for using an HSM in the first place is to prevent exposing raw key data. If you are just testing then consider creating the key in software and then importing it into the HSM. You could also use key wrapping to unwrap the AES key.